# davis.js hash plugin

Tags: javascript, html

i use default demo with 2 links, and alert, now i included hash and title plugin. and my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Davis.extend(Davis.hashRouting({ prefix: "!"}));

    var app = Davis(function () {
        this.use(Davis.title);

        this.configure(function () {
            this.generateRequestOnPageLoad = true
        });
        this.get('/welcome/:name', function (req) {
            alert("Hello " + req.params['name']);
            this.setTitle(req.params['name']);
        });
    });

    app.start();

</script>

    <a href="#!/welcome/oliver">greet oliver</a> //link 1
    <a href="#!/welcome/bob">greet bob</a> //link 1
```

now problem is when i click on link, it redirect me to: *http://localhost/%23!/welcome/bob#!/welcome/bob*
What is the problem ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to put the hash in the href, you will then need to also put the hash in the route definition.

To be honest the hashRouting extension could do with a tidy up, it was contributed by a member of the community and hasn't seen much love recently.  I don't personally use it that often which may be why, so feedback like this is good!

Anyway, I've put up a gist that might help you along here - https://gist.github.com/2994611

Feel free to open an issue on GitHub with any more problems you find and I will give the hashRouting extension some attention for the next release.  Also let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js/issues/44 noone answers :( do you suggest me not to use this plguin ? i realy need it. btw i love davis.js it have analytics, title, seo plugins, it's great

Comment: Ah, sorry, that issue seems to have passed me by,  I'll make an update on that issue with some of the details here and suggestions on what to do next.  Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [glaringly obvious example on the home page](http://davisjs.com) you aren't supposed to put a hashbang in the ahref

```
Set up some links:
    <a href="/welcome/bob">greet bob</a>
```

Comment: i knowm, but i need that becouse when someone go on right click -> open as new tab that it loads url that doesnt exist /welcome/bob doesnt exist

Comment: Then you should redirect those urls with your webserver to the hashbang ones

Comment: if you're using apache, for example, you need to use a mod_rewrite rule so that if a user hits /welcome/bob, you redirect them to #!/welcome/bob . or do it in whatever server router code you are using.